# Fixed Clock and LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

For testing purposes I want to create a fixed `Clock` with a time zone:

```java
Clock c= Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z"), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
//yields FixedClock[2018-04-29T10:15:30Z,Europe/Berlin]
```

Now I want to use the `Clock` wit `LocalDateTime`:

```java
LocalDateTime.now(c);
//yields 2018-04-29T12:15:30
```

Why I'm getting this offset by two hours? Is there a UTC conversion somewhere? What would I have to do to generate a fixed `Clock` with time zone and `LocalDate.now(c)` yields the same time?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `System.out.println(Instant.now(c));
`?

Comment: Then I get the correct time. But to convert that Instant to `LocalDateTime` I would have to use `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(c), ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

Comment: Yes, there is a UTC conversion going on. You specified your fixed time as 10:15:30 UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`), and you specified German time zone. So your clock converts 10:15 UTC to German time and gives you 12:15.

Comment: You should not want to use `LocalDateTime` for a date and time in UTC anyway. Use `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. The latter will even know that it is in UTC (has offset 0 from UTC). For a clock hat gives you a fixed UTC time you may use either of (1) `InstantSource.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z"))` (2) `Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z"), ZoneOffset.UTC)` (3) building on the clock you already have: `c.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z corresponds to 2018-04-29T12:15:30+02:00 and the `LocalDateTime` from this `OffsetDateTime` gives you 2018-04-29T12:15:30; so does your `LocalDateTime.now(c)`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z");
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
        Clock c= Clock.fixed(instant, zoneId);

        // 2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z corresponds to 2018-04-29T12:15:30+02:00
        OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atZone(zoneId).toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);

        // LocalDateTime from this OffsetDateTime results in 2018-04-29T12:15:30
        System.out.println(odt.toLocalDateTime());

        // So does LocalDateTime.now(c)
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(c));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-04-29T12:15:30+02:00
2018-04-29T12:15:30
2018-04-29T12:15:30
```

### How to get your desired output?

You need to use the UTC offset to get the `LocalDateTime` with the same value as the given `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clock c = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-04-29T10:15:30.00Z"), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
        LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.now(c).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-04-29T10:15:30
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/XS0Bin)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Nice answer, somehow I never needed to use `Clock`